# Matroska Muxer filter for DirectShow

Tags: c#, audio, directshow, vorbis, matroska

I'm trying to create graph AudioCapture -> Vorbis Encoder -> Matroska Muxer, but graphedit inserts Vorbis Decoder before Matroska Muxer. I want this graph working without Vorbis Decoder. How can I do this?

Comment: In case you don't find a muxer and going to create one, split it into specific questions when you need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that the multiplexer you are using is unable to accept the Vorbis stream as a valid input. It can be one of the two:

- Something is wrong with media type, and it should be corrected so that both capture and mux accept it
- More likely - the multiplexer implementation has no sufficient support for Vorbis audio, and what you basically need to do is to replace it with the Vorbis-friendly alternative.